# How can I overcome this sort of circular logic?

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm trying to model the velocity of a roller-coaster carriage as it goes down a circular hill.

[image]

To do this first I used energy equations:
$$mgh_1+\frac{1}{2}mu^2=mgh_2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + E$$ (where E is the energy lost to friction and $\theta$ the angle of the carriage makes with the hill)
$$v^2=u^2+2gr-2gr\cos(\theta)-2E/m$$
Then I need the energy lost to friction
$$E=\frac{\int_0^\theta \lvert \mu mg\cos(\theta)-\mu mv^2/r \rvert d\theta}{\theta}2\pi r \theta /2\pi$$
$$E=r\int_0^\theta \lvert \mu mg\cos(\theta)-\mu mv^2/r \rvert d\theta  $$

I can't integrate this though because its not all in terms of $\theta$. The v is changing. I tried again using force equations

$$a=\frac{\int_0^\theta(mg\sin\theta - \mu mg\cos(\theta)+ \mu mv^2/r)d\theta}{\theta} $$ (where a is the average acceleration)

But again there's little I can do here because there's a $v^2$ . Is there anyway I can get out of this loop? I feel like I'm going in circles.

Comment: Question is not clear. Also please take this to physics.stackexchange

Comment: By the way, I don't see any hint of "circular logic" (as it is usually defined) in this question.

Comment: The energy equation alone is enough, *if you do it properly*. For starters, **Do Not Use The Same Variable To Mean Two Different Things**. In particular, your first equation calls two different heights "$h$" and two different speeds "$v$". Clear that up and most of your issues will go away. Write down your equations carefully. Define *all* your variables **exactly**, not with vague phrases like "the angle of the hill the carriage goes down". If you didn't try to take shortcuts, this isn't hard.

Comment: For a first estimation of velocity I'd regard it free of friction. Then, at the top of the hill the carriage must have a $v_0 \gt 0$, otherwise it will stay at the top where no force will accelerate it. Next step, with friction, $v_0$ must be sufficient not to stop within the first few millimetres :)

Comment: @PaulSinclair I honestly tried what you said and still couldn't get the answer. The trouble is that I can only find equations in terms of other equations in terms of that equation. How did you use the energy equation?

Comment: You need to define the initial conditions. Where does the roller coaster start? At the top? Is it already moving, or (essentially) still at that point. If you know the initial height and speed, then you know $h_1$ and $u$. That means the only unknowns left are $h_2$ and $v$. So for each later height $h_2$, you can use the energy equation to find the speed $v$ at that height. And if you don't know the initial height and speed, then you better reframe your problem, because those numbers don't magically appear out of nothing.

Comment: It seems you have difficulty with the fact that the friction is (partly) a function of $v$ but $dv/dt$ is (partly) a function of the friction. This isn't circular logic; it's a motivation for a differential equation. Unlike in some friction-free problems, I don't think there's any convenient way (like energy conservation) to avoid looking at the differential equation itself in some form. Try to construct that equation. And once you have it, you may find that it can only be solved numerically.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice but I think I bit more than I can chew with this one... Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Law.

Let $\theta=0$ be at the top of the sphere, $\theta=\pi/2$ be the far right and so falling straight down.

$mr^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-br^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}+mgr\sin\theta -mgr\mu \cos \theta$

Total Torque is equal to air resistance plus gravity plus kinetic friction. Will probably need a numerical method for that.

So this is non-linear.

This also assumes whatever is keeping the cart attached to the track cancels out  gravity and centrifugal force.

That friction term at the right makes things complicated.

I don't think there is a closed form solution given its resemblance to the kinetic equation for pendulums.